# Sound on browser not working

Tags: windows-7, audio, mixer

The sound on my browser doesn't seem to be working. It's working fine from other media sources but not from my browser. I tried in both chrome and IE. I then tried a fresh install of FF with a fresh install of Flash and still no luck. I also restarted my pc.

I have muted it previously using the volume mixer however none of the browsers show there now, even when running.

Is there some way of resetting the volume mixer to default settings or changing it? Could the issue be with something else?

EDIT: just reinstalled my audio drivers.

EDIT: I have narrowed it down to something to do with flash, either flash is screwed or something is muting my flash content. I tried a [non flash sample](http://www.streamalot.com/wm-embed.shtml) and that played. Reinstalling flash made no diffrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and just reinstalled windows. All working now

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty strange. A user on [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/126881-no-audio-any-browsers-win7.html) forum had the exact same problem. Sound wasn't working on any browser and the browsers weren't showing up in the Volume Mixer. There are four pages in the thread and they provide some helpful links. In the end, the user on the forum had to get their hard drive replaced, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: No offence but you need to read the post. I did clearly detail in the post what I had tried. Both those guides didnt specify anything further